# visual studio : install previous version without massing up

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

I installed VS2008 and VS2015 on my computer that is re-installed with Windows 10 recently. I sometimes have to target to .net framework 2.0/3.0/3.5 in C++/CLI, I had to install VS2008 and VS2010 - Yes, I forgot VS2010.

I know there's no problem about installing different versions of Visual Studio, but it's certain that VS2010 installer will mass up file extension (*.cpp, *.vcxproj, ...) with itself.

Is there any way to install VS2010 without this problem?

Comment: You can target other clr using vs2015, why do you need vs2010?

Answer (score 0):

Targeting different CLRs in VS2015:
[image]

Comment: C++/CLI, not C#... C++/CLI requires preview version of toolset to target preview framework.